# deleting a data table in Excel is not releasing the expected memory, as viewed in task manager

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data table in a worksheet that has 140,000 rows. When I delete it in code, the memory is not released in task manager. It displays 962MB before the delete statement, and 962MB after the delete statement. Why is this? Here is my code:

```
With Workbooks(strWorkbook).Worksheets(strWorksheet).ListObjects(strTable)
    'Remove any filters in the table
    If Not .AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'Delete any existing data in the table
    If .ListRows.Count > 0 Then .DataBodyRange.Delete
End With
```